# sqlite3 row does not work to make fetchall() a dict instead of tuple

Tags: python, sqlite3-python

```
con = sqlite3.connect("funds.db")
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        funds = cur.execute("SELECT * from funds").fetchall()
        print(funds)
```

Since i set `con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row`, i expect funds to return me a dictionary, as my funds is a table. However, when I run .fetchall() even after this, I always get a tuple. Why is this the case if the line of code is supposedly to make fetchall() a dictionary instead of a tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row factory of the cursor is determined when the cursor is created.

In your case you are setting row_factory *after* you've created the cursor.

```py
    cur = con.cursor()
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    print(cur.row_factory) # None
```

You have to move the assignment of the row_factory above the cursor creation:

```py
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cur = con.cursor()
    print(cur.row_factory) # <class 'sqlite3.Row'>
```

Unless you want to change the row factory on the cursor and not on the connection, in which case you have to set if after the cursor is created:

```
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    print(cur.row_factory) # <class 'sqlite3.Row'>
```